# Finding files that contain multiple strings

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to find scripts that contain common malicious code, I need to match multiple strings within each file.  What I am using is working but am not sure why I get the following in the output:

```
# egrep -rli --include='*.php' 'return base64_decode' . | xargs -0 grep -l 'isset'
grep: ./wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/js/menu61.php
./wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/themes.php
./wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/file68.php
./wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/inc/page.php
./wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/inc/template.php
./wp-content/upgrade/include.php
./wp-content/plugins/wp-slimstat/browscap/diff8.php
./wp-content/plugins/quick-contact-form/gallery56.php
./wp-content/plugins/addthis/css/include.php
./wp-content/plugins/addthis/includes/include.php
./wp-content/plugins/tpc-memory-usage/images/code77.php
./wp-content/plugins/gotmls/images/index.php
./wp-content/plugins/tinymce-advanced/langs/object56.php
./wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/dirs70.php
./wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/css/list76.php
./wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/proxy.php
./wp-content/plugins/image-widget/lang/alias.php
./wp-content/plugins/my-page-order/template.php
./wp-content/uploads/2015/01/footer87.php
./wp-content/menu.php
./wp-includes/js/thickbox/db.php
./wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/footer39.php
./wp-includes/js/imgareaselect/general.php
./wp-includes/css/page25.php
./wp-includes/Text/Diff/Engine/dump.php
: No such file or directory
```

The output is good and is what I want but why does it show on line 1:

```
grep: ./wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/js/menu61.php
```

and the last line always shows:

```
: No such file or directory
```

and lastly, piping it into a file doesn't work.

```
# egrep -rli --include='*.php' 'return base64_decode' . | xargs -0 grep -l 'isset' >> asd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is not a result, it's an error message. The format of grep's error when told to search through a non-existent file is `grep: file name: No such file or directory`. For example:

```
$ grep foo bar
grep: bar: No such file or directory
```

That's why you get the `grep:` at the beginning and the `No such file or directory` at the end. That is also why you can't redirect the output to a file, it's being printed to standard error, not standard output and you are redirecting the latter. You can save the output by using `2>>` instead of `>>`. That, however, is not what you want since these are errors.

Your problem is that you're using `-0` with `xargs` which tells it to expect null-separated data. Since your data is actually separated by newlines (each file is on a single line), `xargs` tells `grep` to look for a file of that name (the entire multiline set). What you want to do instead is:

```
 grep -Erli --include='*.php' 'return base64_decode' . | xargs grep -l 'isset'
```

Or, if your file names can contain newlines and you have a version of `grep` that supports it, use grep's `-Z` flag to produce null-separated output:

```
grep -ZErli --include='*.php' 'return base64_decode' . | xargs -0 grep -l 'isset'
```

Also note that I use `grep -E` instead of `egrep`. The `egrep` and `fgrep` are deprecated in favor of `grep -E` and `grep -F`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `xargs` without the `-0` parameter. That parameter tells `xargs` to expect nul-separated arguments, which isn't the case here.